# Postfix SASL authentication via Dovecot - Can I use the SASL login name in my postfix sql queries?

Tags: postfix, sasl

I have a mailserver with `postfix`, `dovecot` and `mysql` running on Debian buster.

Everythings works fine so far, but I would like to setup a scenario where the login name for SASL auth is different from the user part of the recipient domain.

Example:

```
Login name used for SASL auth: myusername
Sender email address: sender@domain.com
```

The authentication with dovecot works fine since I have the login name available as a variable in dovecot.

But before postfix actually submits the email, I would like to verify if the sender address is really owned by the user that logged in. Hence, I added the *smtpd_sender_login_maps* option to the submission service in master.cf, poiting to a mysql table.

```
  -o smtpd_sender_login_maps=proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/sender-login-maps.cf
```

According to the mysql-table manual of postfix (http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html), the only available variables are %s, %u, %d - which all relate to the sender address, ie:

```
%s = sender@domain.com
%u = sender
%d = domain.com
```

Is there any way of using the original SASL login name (*'myusername'*) in my SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured out that accessing the sasl auth username is not required for this purpose.

According to the user manual, the  `smtpd_sender_login_maps` should not return the email addresses owned by the sasl user - it should return the sasl user that owns the sender email address.

http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps

> In all cases the result of table lookup must be either "not found" or a list of SASL login names separated by comma and/or whitespace.

For such a query the sasl username is not required as a variable.